# Getting the id from dynamic custom table, rows

Tags: java, android, onclicklistener

I am creating a table with dynamic custom table rows. I need to get the id in the activity class.

main_Activity-->MyTableLayoutView-->MyTableRow

My Question is, how do i get the id of the cell that was clicked in the table (TextViews) to the main_Activiy.

MyTableRowView:

```
    public void addRow(String[] data, int[] rowId) {
    for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        TextView tv = parseTextView(data[i]);
        tv.setId(rowId[i]);
        tv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                TextView tv2 = (TextView) v;
                clickedText = tv2.getText().toString();
                Debug.debugMsg(clickedText + " " + tv2.getId());
            }
        });
        this.addView(tv);
    }
}
```

As far as I can get is getting the id from the TablerowView class, but I need it to be in Activity class, Please if anyone can enlighten me. Thanks in advance.

Activity class:

```
    private void showTables() {
    db.open();
    db.importDb();// TODO
    table = new TableLayoutView(this,Converter.toArrayListStringArray(db.getDbTablesForChoose()));
    table.addDataListArray(Converter.toArrayListStringArray(db.getDbTablesForChoose()),true);
    llChooseSQLTable.addView(table);
}
```

TableLayoutView:

```
    public void addDataListArray(ArrayList<String[]> data, boolean header) {

    for (int i = 0; i < ROW_NUMBERS; i++) {
        TableRowView tableRow = new TableRowView(context);

        tableRow.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

        tableRow.addRow(data.get(i),idHandler.getNextIdsRow());//idHandles passes unique id.
        this.addView(tableRow); 
    }
}
```

Comment: `tv2.getId()` is given an error or what?

Comment: No, the above code works, but all I can do now is getId() from the TableRowView, and need it let the activity class know the id which was clicked.

Comment: Ok. Could post an example of how you used your custom TableRowView in your activity?

Comment: TableRow is created By TableLayout. or is the properway of doing it is creating it in activity? I will post the codes.

Comment: and one TableRowView has only one TextView, right?

Comment: No, at the moment is only one textView, but I will add edittext and buttons later on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you are able to get the ID from your code above. If your primary concern is propagating that id from the view back up to the parent class then you could do it in multiple ways. One way is to get the context of the view then cast it to the specific activity and call a function within that activity, e.g. within the onClick() operation:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
  ((MyActivity)v.getContext()).insertNotificationMethod(v.getId());
}
```

Where your activity is called MyActivity and you implement a method called insertNotificationmethod which takes an integer. This would work only if this view is always within this function, and even then it is a rather crude way to do it.

You could also just directly call it within the onClick() method using:

```
MyActivity.this.insertNotificationMethod(v.getId());
```

However, this way of doing things would limit this view to only be useful within this particular activity.

For a more generic way, you could BroadcastReceivers which may be a little more complicated that you would like. For more information about those you could check out the Android documentation here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html

Hopefully that helps.

Comment: Would it be a proper way of doing this if I: public void onClick(View v) {
  ((MyActivity)v.getContext()).insertNotificationMethod(v);
}//return the whole view to the activity.

Comment: You could do that. You could also just look-up the view if you wanted via findViewById(int). Either way should work.

Answer (score 0):

The only solution that I can think of is to move your `addRow()` and `addDataListArray()` methods to the Activity *with some modefication*:

```
public void addRow(String[] data, int[] rowId, TableRowView tableRow) {
for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    TextView tv = parseTextView(data[i]);
    tv.setId(rowId[i]);
    tv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            TextView tv2 = (TextView) v;
            clickedText = tv2.getText().toString();
            clickedId = tv2.getId());
        }
    });
    tableRow.addView(tv);
}
}

public void addDataListArray(ArrayList<String[]> data, boolean header, TableLayoutView table) {

for (int i = 0; i < ROW_NUMBERS; i++) {
    TableRowView tableRow = new TableRowView(context);

    tableRow.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

    addRow(data.get(i),idHandler.getNextIdsRow(), tableRow);//idHandles passes unique id.
    table.addView(tableRow); 
}
}
```

And in your Activity change this line:

```
//table.addDataListArray(Converter.toArrayListStringArray(db.getDbTablesForChoose()),true);
addDataListArray(Converter.toArrayListStringArray(db.getDbTablesForChoose()),true, table);
```

Although I don't know if other part of your app will be affected by this *huge* modification I made.

Good luck!